# Is it possible to use a else if inside of a patchValue()

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to know if it's possible to use a else if function to evaluate condition and base on a user selection, it set a different value

Example:

```
typeRequest(){
If(inboundAddress != "") {
 RequestType: Inbound
}else (inboundAddess == "") {
RequestType: notSelected}
```

I would like to use a patchValue around this function to store the RequestType value in the formcontrolname.

Please assist on the how if possible... And if not please give an idea of how I can accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

The PatchValue updates a subset of the elements of the FormGroup or FormArray. It will only update the matching objects and ignores the rest.

```
patchValue(value: { [key: string]: any; }, options: { onlySelf?: boolean; emitEvent?: boolean; } = {}): void
```

Maybe use a ternary operator in place of a variable object's value:

```
<your_condition> ? <expression_A> : <expression_B>
```